# How to check empty data Json parse JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have this function

```
       function GetSomeDetails(Param)
       {
          Json_Parameters = JSON.stringify(Param);
          $.ajax({

              type: "POST",
              url: "MainPage.aspx/MyMethod",
              data: JSON.stringify({ "Param": Json_Parameters }),

              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (result)

              {

                  var json = result.d;
                  obj = JSON.parse(json);
                  if (JSON.stringify(obj) == '{}'){
                      alert('it is empty');
                  } else{
                      alert('it is not empty');  }

                 } 

                 });

             }
```

I get this error when it is empty.

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character JSON data

Comment: Can you not try `json.length` to get an idea if the object is empty or not?

Comment: JSON.parse(json || '{}')

Comment: @VivekPradhan Yes I tried if(json.length<0) {alert('empty') ;} else {alert('not empty'); }

Comment: @TSV Where I use this ?

Comment: "obj = JSON.parse(json || '{}');" or "obj = (json && json.length !== 0) ? JSON.parse(json) : undefined;"

Comment: @TSV how json!==0 its throwing an error

Comment: @Mhmt whether my comment was helpful?

Comment: @Mhmt what do you get in the json variable? can you log it in the console and show it here?

Comment: I solved in my sql query.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

Check if Json object length less than or **equal to** zero then it is empty

```
if(json.length<=0) 
{
   alert('empty') ;
} 
else 
{
   alert('not empty'); 
}
```